# Vuetify pagination not cycling through on button click

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt3

I am having trouble implementing Veutify's pagination component to cycle through my array.

```
<template>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-5">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in pagedAssets" :key="`asset_index_${index}`">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
    <v-pagination
      v-model="pageNo"
      :length="numPages"
    ></v-pagination>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script setup>
let pageSize = 4;
let pageNo = 1;
let assets = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"];

const numPages = computed(() => {
  // calculate the number of pages we have
  return Math.ceil(assets.length / pageSize);
});

const pagedAssets = computed(() => {
  // get the start index for your paged result set.
  // The page number starts at 1 so the active item in the pagination is displayed properly.
  // However for our calculation the page number must start at (n-1)
  const startIndex = (pageNo - 1) * pageSize;

  // create a copy of your assets list so we don't modify the original data set
  const data = [...assets];

  // only return the data for the current page using splice
  return data.splice(startIndex, pageSize);
});
</script>
```

I am expecting when cycling through that the items will update.

Comment: `computed` recalculates whenever any of the reactive values inside it changes. In your case, you want `pageNo` reactive. If you plan on changing `assets` or `pageSize`, and the pagination to automatically update, you have to make them reactive, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pageNo` is a `v-model` variable so it should be reactive but you are using it as a static variable that's why it is not updating. you need to use `ref` to make it reactive.

Replace your script with this-

```
<script setup>
import { computed, ref } from "vue";
  
let pageSize = 4;
let pageNo = ref(1);
let assets = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"];

const numPages = computed(() => {
  // calculate the number of pages we have
  return Math.ceil(assets.length / pageSize);
});

const pagedAssets = computed(() => {
  // get the start index for your paged result set.
  // The page number starts at 1 so the active item in the pagination is displayed properly.
  // However for our calculation the page number must start at (n-1)
  const startIndex = (pageNo.value - 1) * pageSize;

  // create a copy of your assets list so we don't modify the original data set
  const data = [...assets];

  // only return the data for the current page using splice
  return data.splice(startIndex, pageSize);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `pageNo` to be reactive, you can achieve that by making it a `ref` instead. You can read more about it here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html

Here is a working example for your specific case: [Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)